# error del tipo ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python, lista, números-primos

estoy tratando de simular el algoritmo de eratostenes para hallar todos los primos menores que un
numero n que es ingresado por el usario, con python.

```
import numpy as np
#n = int(input('dame un numero: '))
p = [*range(2,n,1)]
t = np.array([])
i=2
while i<n: 
    j=i 
    while j<n: 
        j = j+i
        p.remove(j)
    t = np.append(t,i)
    p.remove(i)
    i = min(p) 
    
print(p)
```

pero al momento de ingresar el numero y que me haga toda esa operacion, me sale esto.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-f34aca25e366> in <module>
      8     while j<n:
      9         j = j+i
---> 10         p.remove(j)
     11     t = np.append(t,i)
     12     p.remove(i)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

me dice que ese elemento no esta en esa lista, lo cual no me hace ningun sentido, lo probe manualmente para un n=3 y nada. se que debo estar ignorando algo pero no se que. que creen que pueda hacer

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tratas de borrar varias veces el mismo número: cuando borras 2 de la lista, también borras 4, 6, 8, etc.

El siguiente candidato es 3, por lo cual deberias borrar 6, 9, ..., pero el 6 ya no está; lo borraste al procesar el 2.

No es necesario calcular el `min(p)`; el menor valor siempre estará en el primer lugar de la lista.

No necesitas numpy tampoco, una lista basta y sobra.

He aqui el código correcto:

```
n = int(input('dame un numero: '))
candidatos = [* range(2, n + 1)]
primos = []
i = 2
while True:
    # i es primo, agregarlo a la lista.
    primos.append(i)
    # recorrer los candidatos eliminado los
    # multiplos de i.
    for j in range(i, n + 1, i):
        if j in candidatos:
            candidatos.remove(j)

    if not candidatos:
        # Si la lista quedo vacia, terminar.
        break;

    # Coger el primer elemento de los candidatos restantes
    i = candidatos[0]

print(primos)
```

produce:

```
dame un numero: 100
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! me vi dando cuenta, antes de leer tu respuesta, de que ciertamente estaba borrando numeros que ya había borrado. Al final decidí reemplazar la parte del while que recorre todos los múltiplos con un bucle for, que es mas eficiente. tal como tu lo hiciste.